# composer vendor name format for nested directory

Tags: php, git, composer-php, directory-structure

The standard package name format for a composer package is `vendor/pkName`. 
I've this following directory structure:

```
 - myVendorName

    - extensions
      - yii2
        -Ext1
        -Ext2 and so on

    - bundles
      - bundle1
      - bundle2
      - bundle3 and so on

    - toolkit
     - forlder1
     - folder2 and so on
```

This is the organization that I gave in my harddisk, but the real projects are like:

```
  - myVendorName/extensions/yii2/ext1
  - myVendorName/extensions/yii2/ext2
  - myVendorName/bundles/bundle1
  - myVendorName/bundles/bundle2
  - myVendorName/bundles/bundle3
  - myVendorName/toolkit
```

My questions about this:

1. It's possible to store all in one git repository and require with composer only the needed subpackages (for example: require only `myVendorName/toolkit` and `myVendorName/bundles/bundle3`)
2. It's possible to maintain the extended name format with composer (so in `composer.json` require section, require for `myVendorName/bundles/bundle3` instead of `myVendorName/bundle3`)

Is there a way to achieve these 2 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve (1) by using git subtree split. Using this method, you split seperate directories of the main repository into a new repository and push it to github. This way, all packages still have their own repository, but you only have to maintain one repository (lots of big projects use this, like Symfony, Laravel, etc.).

(2) is not supported. You can use something like `my_vendor/third-bundle` instead of `my_vendor/bundles/third`. The directory isn't important anyways, as Composer will just perfectly autoload all classes inside the packages (if they have the correct autoloading config).

Answer (score 0):

> It's possible to store all in one git repository and require with
>   composer only the needed subpackages (for example: require only
>   "myVendorName/toolkit" and "myVendorName/bundles/bundle3")

Yes. If you have the same components in different projects that may require specific set of dependencies, consider making them a reusable package instead of an empty package with composer.json. Also notice that `require-dev` is being resolved [only in root package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev).

> It's possible to maintain the extended name format with composer (so
>   in composer.json require section, require for
>   "myVendorName/bundles/bundle3" instead of "myVendorName/bundle3"

Yes. In [`repositories`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories), provide `vcs` or `package` repository and make it resolve `myVendorName/bundles/bundle3`. `url` in `vcs` may refer to local git repo. There's no simple way to alias "myVendorName/bundle3" as "myVendorName/bundles/bundle3", which makes the idea unpractical.